# building a search functionality

Tags: java, performance, salesforce-apex

I am trying to search account table by providing a search string. I am building a query based in different conditions and then adding the returned records in a list.

The functionality is working correctly but I want to know how an below method be further optimized.

```
    public PageReference search(){
    clear();
    runningUserId = Userinfo.getUserId();
    String searchquery;
    Boolean existUser = AccSearchAccess__c.getValues(runningUserId) !=null? true : false;
    if(existUser){
        searchquery='Select  Name,Id,AccessLevel__c FROM Account where Name like \'%'+accountName+'%\'';
    }
    else{
        set<id> accountIds = new set<id>();
        List<WMAccess__c> wmaLst = [Select id,Account__c from WMAccess__c where WM_User__c = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
        for(WMAccess__c wm : wmaLst){
            accountIds.add(wm.Account__c);
        }
        if(!accountIds.isEmpty()){
            searchquery='Select  Name,Id,AccessLevel__c FROM Account where Name like \'%'+accountName+'%\' AND id IN:accountIds';
        }
    }

    accList= Database.query(searchquery);
    if(accList.size()>0)
        for(Account acc : accList){
            AccountWrapper aw = new AccountWrapper(acc, false);
            aw.accountId = acc.id; 
            aw.accountName = acc.Name;
            aw.accountAccess = acc.AccessLevel__c;
            accountsList.add(aw);
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Avoid building raw SQL Strings. use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @CrazyNinja - I further cleaned my code, but i didn't get what do you mean by PreparedStatement
Could you please post a sample?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exposed an injection vulnerability.

```
'WHERE Name like \'%'+accountName+'%\''
```

Any time you merge user input into your query, you should call `String.escapeSingleQuotes`, or better yet, use a dynamic binding.

```
// OK
searchQuery += 'WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountName) + '%\'';

// BETTER
String fuzzySearchTerm = '%' + accountName + '%';
searchQuery += 'WHERE Name LIKE :fuzzySearchTerm';
```